# why does tkinter widgets doesnt appear in vscode?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
button1 = ttk.Label(root, text = 'lol')
button1.pack()
```

And when i try to run the program only the window show up but without the button.

it gives me this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TclError
NULL main window
  File "C:\Users\Elad\Desktop\coding\tkintertut.py", line 6, in <module>
    button1 = ttk.Label(root, text = 'lol')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root.mainloop()` has to be at the end of the code for the window to be shown, not right after declaration of `root`.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

button1 = ttk.Label(root, text = 'lol')
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Explanation:**

Only the lines of code between `root` and `root.mainloop()` gets executed as long as the window is open, if you close the window, the `Labels` and all other widget declared after `root.mainloop()` become active but, the window is now closed and `root` is destroyed, hence the error. But here in my answer, the code between `root` and `root.mainloop()` has everything I need to be in the window and hence it shows the complete window. Just keep in mind to always say `root.mainloop()` at the end of the code only

Hope it cleared your errors. Do let me know if any more errors or doubts.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your `root.mainloop()` should be the last code!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
button1 = ttk.Label(root, text = 'lol')
button1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```